# Uploading ArcGIS table to SQL Server

Tags: arcmap, sql-server

I am able to import a table created in SQL Server into ArcMap by using database connection.

Can I also do a reverse process i.e. upload an ArcMap table back into SQL Server. I am using ArcMap version of 10.6.1?

Comment: Did you try to do it ? if yes what did you try and what didn't work ?

Comment: While ArcGIS can load table data into PostgreSQL without an Enterprise geodatabase, the other RDBMSes require an Enterprise geodatabase installed and licensed within the database to utilize tools like FeatureClassToFeatureClass or FeatureClassToGeodatabase to copy data.  I've written Python code to export layers as SQL statements (CREATE TABLE, INSERT..., CREATE INDEX ...) to both SQL Server and PostgreSQL, using `arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute()`, so it is possible, even if not an EGDB. Please [Edit] the question to specify whether an Enterprise geodatabase is present and what you have tried.

Comment: I have not tried anything yet. I am a new user to ArcGIS. I used to work in Mapinfo and now shifted to ArcGIS. In Mapinfo it was easier to load/import table from SQL using DBMS connection. Similarly it was also easy to export table to SQL server using inbuilt Mapinfo tool called "Easyloader". I was wondering that if ArcGIS provide similar type of toll to export table to SQL server.

Comment: Beside I have both licensed ArcMap 10.6.1 and ArcGIS Pro. I can google meanwhile how arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute() command works.